# Not able to give CRUD permissions to custom object on Customer Community Plus Login User Standard Profile

Tags: custom-object, profile, customer-community, licenses

[Profile Screnshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncqwv.png)

I need give access to Customer Community Plus Login User to one of my custom objects,this user should be able to crete and delete the records of the custom objects.

However, when I go to Profiles object permissions page, I see everything disabled  ,even the standard object.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Here is the salesforce documentation with the permissions associated with the `Customer Community Plus` / `Customer Community Plus Login License`.... https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5   I'm kind of stumped here because you're saying you don't have access to the std. objects.   
 can you post some screen shots of the profile and the permissions associated with it?  FYI There doesn't seem to be a known issue in SF either https://success.salesforce.com/search?type=Issues&keywords=Customer+Community+Plus

Comment: Added image for the profile screenshot

Answer (score 2):

You can only update object permission for custom profiles only. Customer Community Plus Login User is standard profile that meant to be just assign to user. If you need to change permission of this profile, then clone it and give extra permission as per your requriement and assign this profile to your users.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can give custom object permissions using permission set. This is again at user level.
2. Write apex code to assign custom permissions on creation of specific profile user.